# Getting salespeople from same sales area with different zip codes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to display customers who live in the same city as `William`. In my `customer` table I have zip codes as `zipCode` column. In my `city` table I have city names as `cityName`.

**Table city**:

```
zipCode (PK) cityName, stateCode
```

**Table customer**:

```
customerId (PK) customerName, customerAddress, zipCode (FK)
```

My query so far...

```
SELECT 
    cu2.customerName AS 'Customer Name', 
    ci2.cityName AS 'City Name'
FROM 
    customer as cu
INNER JOIN 
    city as ci ON cu.zipCode = ci.zipCode
INNER JOIN 
    city as ci2 ON ci.cityName = ci2.cityName
INNER JOIN 
    customer as cu2 ON ci2.zipCode = cu2.zipCode
                    AND cu2.customerName <> cu.customerName
WHERE 
    cu2.customerName = 'William'
```

It shows no results because I think it is only checking for William's zip code when the city he is in has two other zip codes. His is 91709 and the cityNAME has in addition 91708 and 91710. I need to get the other customers within that cityNAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take your schema as:

> customer (customerid, customerName, cityid, ...)
>
> city (cityid, cityName, zip, ...)

To retrieve the customers who live in the same city as 'William', you will need

```
SELECT cust.customerName, cit.city_name
FROM customer cust
JOIN city cit ON cust.cityid = cit.cityid
WHERE cit.cityid IN (
     SELECT cit2.cityid
     FROM city cit2
     JOIN customer cust2 ON cit2.cityid = cust2.cityid
     WHERE cust2.customerName = 'William'
)
```

Comment: Then show me your schema - just the table names and columns inside.

Comment: My tables are in the question, also this query already does what mine does. It does not however take into account that there are more than one zipCode in the cityName. This only checks for the customers zipCode.

Comment: I am unable to edit my answer. It is giving page not found error.
Just do one thing - replace the `cityid` with `zipCode` in the code I have given. That should work.

Comment: Why am I not able to edit my answer or post a new answer??? I have a suitable answer for this question!!! Somebody help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ct.customerName
FROM city c JOIN customer ct ON c.ZipCode = ct.ZipCode
WHERE c.CityName IN (
                     SELECT c.CityName
                     FROM customer ct JOIN city c ON ct.ZipCode = c.ZipCode 
                     WHERE ct.CustomerName = 'William'
                     )
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. My query already does this. The problem/question is how to get it to know the other zipCodes in the customer's city NAME.